# https://infra.devskills.app/interactive-presentation/api/4.0.0 clearifition needed on this API for PUT method

Tags: crud

I am using the (https://infra.devskills.app/interactive-presentation/api/4.0.0) API, and when I make a PUT request, no data is being returned. I have already posted the data and I am trying to retrieve it using the ID, but I am still unable to get the data. If you look at their website, it says to use the following endpoint to get the next slide: ([https://infra.devskills.app/api/interactive-presentation/v4/presentations/{presentationID}/polls/current](https://infra.devskills.app/api/interactive-presentation/v4/presentations/%7BpresentationID%7D/polls/current)) I know that the PUT method is usually used to update data, but I'm not sure why we are using the PUT method here to get the next slide. I tried using Postman, but I keep receiving a 404 error. Can someone please explain how to use the PUT method to get the next slide?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, in my route handler I was sending `res.send` as an object e.g `{success: true, payload: data}` where as in the test it was expecting the data so when I changed it to `res.send{data}` it worked.